# How to disable all networking for a running process in Linux?

Tags: networking

What is the least convoluted way to do it? To start a process with no networking, `unshare -n -r` does the job reliably.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good way to do this. You can't move a process into another network namespace, so you can't accomplish the exact equivalent of your `unshare` command. Standard iptables or nftables does not have the ability to block traffic by pid. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195254/4989) suggests moving the process into a cgroup and then blocking network access for that cgroup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to unshare network for current process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457117/how-to-unshare-network-for-current-process)

Comment: Can't say it's least convoluted, but it's the nearest goal, since it does as what is asked.

Comment: @A.B Thank you for the link! I will attempt that method and report back. :)

Comment: The answer that @larsks shared seems to me like the cleanest most reliable way, much better than the `gdb` solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block network access of a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/block-network-access-of-a-process)

Comment: @MC68020 It's already linked from the first comment by larsks. And to answer: it might, will try.